# How to get all atrribute labels in yii 1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have Brand table(it contains brand_id, brand_name, b_year )  and this code

```
`Products::model()->getAttributeLabel('brand_id')` 
var_dump(Products::model()->getAttributeLabel('brand_id'));
```

It shows only brand_id label. How can I show all labels instead of one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var_dump(Products::model()->attributeLabels());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hii  `attributeLabels()` is a `function` in `Model`. It return a `array` with `database` field as key.

to get all labels you have to just call it with no agruments like

```
var_dump(Products::model()->attributeLabels()); // this will return complete array
```

Where as `getAttributeLabel` is written in `CActiveRecord` and it expect and argument by definition it will not given all fields lablels

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
$lables = Products::model()->attributeLabels();
print_r($labels);
```

`$lables` returns all labels from `Products` model.